# How to make a server to send arduino sensors data to use it in my java application

Tags: java, server, arduino, appdomain

I have an arduino device and i want to send the arduino sensors data to a server so i can fetch the data and store it in sqlite database and use it in my java application.

I already bought a domain name from goDaddy but I don’t know to do next, can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a server, and you may be able to get one for free, but if you can't than you would need to rent a server from one of the many companies offering such service. You can get one from Amazon AWS, Google GCP, or smaller but not less reliable companies like Digital Ocean.

You need the minimum and least expensive configuration of a virtual machine which you will connect to using SSH text terminal. For instance you can get a Linux server and have your code run behind Apache webserver.

You can send data from Arduino to your server using simple GET strings over HTTP/S or utilize MQTT if you need the server to also send commands to the board.